What is "don't let me get me"?
So I was listening to Sawano Hiroyuki's music ViEW on YouTube when I read this comment:

In case anyone is wondering, "Don't let me get me" means "Don't let me hurt myself." There's actually a song called "Don't let me get me" by P!nk

which surprised me a little because it's not some kind of Engrish, but a reference (?) to an actual song of the same name by an American singer.
But then what is the expression "get me" as defined in a dictionary? I can't find it in the Oxford Learner's Dictionaries, my first go-to source, but there are two very similar phrasal verbs: get at me (to keep criticizing me) and get to me (to annoy or affect me). Is "get me" just one of either expression omitting an at/to? And can someone please explain the subtle nuances of meaning of "get at somebody" and "get to somebody"?
Urban Dictionary does have this exact term gets me:

To make an individual emotional. Whether happy, angry, sad, et cetera.
Also known as gets to me. This is a vague term, so you will have to make a judgement call as to what emotion they are trying to convey.

and it sides with "get me" being "get to me" while the YouTube comment seems to define it as "get at me". So which one is it?

"Get" is one of those multi-purpose words that mean almost anything, especially in a song.

@MichaelHarvey Yes, and that is why it's hard for me to "get it". Dictionaries are almost always useless in cases like this, so I need a human's help.

But the meaning is not clear. It probably means 'harm myself' in some way. But maybe not. Questions asking for interpretation of song lyrics are often considered to be off-topic on here.

@MichaelHarvey How about rewording the question a bit to ask for just the subtle nuances of meaning of "get at somebody" and "get to somebody"? And if "get somebody" is a phrase by itself or a contraction of one of the above?

As an elderly native BrE speaker I've never heard the phrase  "get me" used to mean some form of self harm. Maybe it's AmE??  As an aside the phrase "get you" is a somewhat, possibly camp, way of deriding someone who is taking on airs and graces. I suppose it could be used against the speaker as self deprecation, but not in the context of the OP's question.

I believe the underlying literal context is animal predation.  The verb "get" there means "seize (and maim or kill)".  Don't go out in the dark. The bogey-man will get you.   "He was hiking alone in the foothills and a mountain-lion got him."

In the song lyric "me" is both predator and victim/prey: "Don't let me get me".The lyric contains the line "I'm a hazard to myself".  But it also contains the lines "I'm my own worst enemy
/ It's bad when you annoy yourself" so the monster/predator metaphor (via the verb "get") is a form of exaggeration.

It's used in the song because it's a striking phrase (short, memorable, unusual), not because it's a well-known phrase. As a slang term, and not a widely used one, it's unlikely to be in a dictionary. And if it's not in a dictionary, what do you want to know?

I wouldn't call this use of get "slang".   It's an everyday usage not confined to a particular group or age-range and has been around for over 100 years.

As noted in the comments, get is a multi-purpose word in English and can mean a lot of things. The meaning you're talking about is actually different from "get at __" or "get to __." This meaning of get [noun/pronoun] comes from using get to mean to "catch" or "acquire." For example:

If I am talking about a pay increase at work, I might say:
I heard there will be raises this year. I hope I get one.


If I am talking about a job I want, someone might tell me:
You should get it - you're so qualified!


Two children are playing tag. One catches the other and says:
Got you!


If I want my cat to catch an insect that's annoying me, I could say:
Go get it!

In this last two examples, get is being used to mean "hunt," and that is the origin of the meaning you're seeing here. Here are some more idiomatic hunting/hurting examples:

Someone opens a door and accidentally hits their friend in the head. The friend's head now hurts. The friend might say:
Oww, you really got me.


A movie character is mad a classmate who has now done something rude. The character says:
I'm gonna get him good.
(This means "I'm going to beat him up")


You are cutting vegetables in the kitchen and accidentally cut your finger. Later, a friend asks you what happened.
I got myself while cutting carrots.


You return from a fishing trip with a large fish. You show it to your cousin and she says
Wow! You got a big one!

As you can see, this pattern can be used whether the catching/hurting/hunting was intentional (fishing, beating someone up) or unintentional (cutting oneself with a knife by accident, hitting someone with a door by accident).
While Don't let me get me is not a common phrase - you wouldn't usually hear this outside of a song - but it makes sense in this context. Here, get has become synonymous (in this context) with hurt.
-> Note - it would be more grammatically correct to say "don't let me get myself" but the reflexive is being dropped as a stylistic choice because it's a song.

It definitely makes sense when I read it like this, makes me wonder if get at __ and get to __ are just variations with different preposition preferences, because they all have the "hunting" context.

@Gao Sometimes! "Get at _" can sometimes mean "attack" or "hunt" like "I can't wait to get at the cake" means to eat the cake and comes from a hunting context. In other contexts, "get at _" is a step removed from hunting though. For example, "Do you see what I'm getting at?" means "Do you understand what I mean?" which does also come from the idea of "get" meaning "to hunt" as in "to target" or "to hone in on" but  there isn't as direct a path

@Gao "Get to _" most commonly means either "am allowed to"/ "have the opportunity to" as in "I can't believe I get to go to the zoo for my birthday!" or means "reach" or "arrive at" like "When we get to the park, we'll have a picnic." These are less connected to the hunting idea but still connect to the basic definition of acquiring something (either an opportunity or a place)
